# Selecting between an exact date and a range date

Tags: forms

I have several form controls on a list view that allow for filtering criteria on certain dates. We'd like to allow our customers to select between specifying an exact date or specifying a date range that the criteria could fall between.

The best I can come up with is making it a two-part form control with the first part as so:
[image: step one]

If "exact date" is selected, the radio buttons are replaced with:

[image: exact date form]

If "between dates" is selected, the radio buttons are replaced with:

[image: between dates]

This definitely works, but feels like a lot of fields. Are there other options that might express the form control in a more compact or simple way?

Comment: If the user mistakenly selects "exact date" how does he change his selection?

Comment: why replace them? Why not leave the date field invisible unless the right radio button is checked? Think the "other (please specify)" option many forms use.

Comment: That's a good point. That definitely makes more sense and I'll do that if I end up going with this format. I was just wondering if there aren't any other common patterns for this form control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some flight ticket searching websites face a similar issue this way:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwr6n6.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The Return input is not actually disabled, when you click it then you can select a date. In your case this might work in a similar way.

**The idea in your case is to make one of the inputs valid for both situations**. The starting date and the exact date could probably be it. 
The input for the finishing date is always visible so if left empty it is an exact date, if selected then it implies there is an end date. This way you avoid an extra step of preselecting the radio buttons. Also make sure that there is a way to go back to make the End date input null again.

Comment: Well put, I think you explained the functionality that must occur exactly right. I like this example better than the one I came up with. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad it could help :)

Comment: @Alvaro, nice answer -- where were you when I ask this question? http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/95655/are-placeholders-good-for-default-values -- you are using a “placeholder as a default value” in this example. Maybe you can share your insights using them?

Comment: I've been active here only the last month and a half or so :p I left an answer with some thoughts in your question.